# Quais os critérios para failbit e badbit em um std::istream?

Tags: c++, exceção

Em um exercício de C++, propõe-se armazenar um dado (numérico, inteiro - ex.: `4` ou `-3650`) inserido pelo usuário através do console. Trata-se de um exercício para lidar com tratativas de exceções e "programação defensiva".

Tanto a apostila quando o exercício em si fazem apologia ao uso de `std::cin.fail()` para identificar um dado inválido e tratar isso dentro de um `try...catch`. Até aí tudo bem - eu até mesmo já completei o exercício - e tudo funciona como proposto.

No entanto, nem a apostila, nem o exercício ou qualquer outro recurso que pude encontrar dá detalhes satisfatórios para que eu possa aferir o **critério** que causa o flag de erro em `std::cin`. [Na documentação de C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/) encontrei explicação acerca da existência dos *flags de erro* retornados pela função `fail()`, inclusive sobre `failbit` e `badbit` - porém fiquei em dúvida sobre a "*lógica interna da própria operação*".

Por observação e de acordo com o trecho abaixo:

> failbit is generally set by an operation when the error is related to the internal logic of the operation itself

Se considerarmos:

```
int x = 0;
std::cout << "Digite um número: ";
cin >> x; // stackoverflow

if (std::cin.fail()) {
    std::cout << "A operação falhou porquê tentei armazenar uma string em int\n";
}
```

Entendo que `std::cin.fail()` retornaria `true` (`failbit`) neste caso **porquê** tentamos armazenar um `const char*`/`string` em uma variável do tipo `int`.

Está correto?

---

**[Bonus]**: Se estiver correto, e eu estiver armazenando em uma `string`, o que poderia ser considerado uma condição de falha (`failbit`) ou de erro (`badbit`) para o `istream`? Como seria possível causar esse erro?

> Lembrando que este é um exemplo puramente educacional. O propósito no exercício era utilizar `std::cin.fail()` para tratar erros simples mas a curiosidade me fez desejar expandir o contexto (então ajuda saber quais as limitações dessa técnica, vantagens/desvantagens). Obrigado!

Comment: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) é um lugar melhor para buscar informação sobre C++.

Comment: Acho que seu entendimento está certo. Complementando com o que está descrito em cppreference (linkada por @MárioFeroldi), failbit indica uma “falha de conversão de tipos” ou “nenhum caracter lido”, enquanto que badbit tem mais a ver com erros de escrita como “disco cheio”, “falha ao alocar memória”, etc. Para aumentar a confusão, algumas operações podem setar vários bits ao mesmo tempo e fail() testa tanto failbit quanto badbit... (como só estou confirmando sua suposição e não tenho tempo para fazer alguns testes, postei só como comentário)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Quais os critérios para failbit e badbit em um std::istream?

O padrão que especifica a linguagem, *Standard for Programming
Language C ++*, diz:

> Table 109 — iostate effects
>
> - **badbit** indicates a loss of integrity in an input or output sequence (such as an irrecoverable read error from a file);
> - **eofbit** indicates that an input operation reached the end of an input sequence;
> - **failbit** indicates that an input operation failed to read the expected characters, or that an output operation failed to generate
>     the desired characters.

Traduzindo:

- **badbit** indica a perda da integridade de uma sequência de entrada ou saída (como um erro irrecuperável na leitura de um arquivo);
- **eofbit** indica que uma operação de entrada alcançou o fim de uma sequência de entrada;
- **failbit** indica que uma operação de entrada falhou em ler os caracteres esperados, ou que uma operação de saída falhou em gerar os caracteres desejados.

OBSERVAÇÃO: O texto foi copiado do rascunho do C++17(arquivo PDF). Para fins de referência, o rascunho do C++20 oferece o mesmo texto: https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/source/iostreams.tex

Um jeito de explicar de modo simples e direto é:

- **badbit** quando algum erro sem conserto acontece na stream. Você deve destruir a instância, pois qualquer outra operação não oferece garantias que funcionará.
- **failbit** quando o uso de algum recurso da stream não funcionou como esperado neste momento, mas a stream em si está intacta. Tente novamente até acertar.

> Entendo que std::cin.fail() retornaria true (failbit) neste caso
>   porquê tentamos armazenar um const char*/string em uma variável do
>   tipo int.
>
> Está correto?

**Não**, mas quase lá. Você está lendo uma string da stream `cin`, tentando interpretar ela como um número decimal, e armazenando ela como um número inteiro na variável `x`.

Você recebe `failbit` se a string não for um número decimal, ou se o número exceder o tamanho máximo especificado para o tipo `int`.

> Se estiver correto, e eu estiver armazenando em uma string, o que
>   poderia ser considerado uma condição de falha (failbit) ou de erro
>   (badbit) para o istream? Como seria possível causar esse erro?

Existem vários meios de causar um badbit. Várias causas são listadas no link https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate, citado por [Mário Feroldi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/333937/quais-os-crit%C3%A9rios-para-failbit-e-badbit-em-um-stdistream#comment675626_333937). Pode ser originada por métodos naturais e artificiais.

Um exemplo de meio natural é:

```
std::cin.rdbuf(nullptr);
std::cin.unget();
```

O método artificial é:

```
std::cin.setstate(std::ios_base::badbit);
```

Um exemplo completo baseado no código da pergunta:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <streambuf>

int main()
{
    int x = 0;    
    try {
        std::cout << "Digite um número: ";
        std::cin.exceptions(std::ios_base::failbit | std::ios_base::badbit);
        //std::cin.rdbuf(nullptr);//badbit natural
        //std::cin.unget();//badbit natural
        //std::cin.setstate(std::ios_base::badbit);//badbit artificial
        std::cin >> x;//failbit
        std::cout << (x + 1);//se digitou 11, retornarei 12
    } catch (std::ios_base::failure& fail) {
        std::cout << "\nerro nr " << fail.code().value() << "\n";//igual para fail e bad no GCC
        std::cout << fail.what() << "\n";//igual para fail e bad no GCC    
        if (std::cin.bad()) {
            std::cout << "falha catastrófica \n";
        } else {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::stringbuf stream;
            std::cin >> &stream;
            std::cout << "não foi legal digitar " << &stream << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interessante! Obrigado pela elaboração dos fatos e os exemplos. Vou apenas dar o tempo do bounty para ver se alguém mais aparece e tem algo mais a acrescentar. :)